# AttributeError: '_io.BufferedWriter' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to take emojis from one server and add them to my server. I'm getting an error when it gets to the line where I'm actually adding the emoji with `client.create_custom_emoji`.

Error: 

`AttributeError: '_io.BufferedWriter' object has no attribute 'startswith'`

Full: 

`Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\bot\Desktop\bottest\bot.py", line 2429, in on_message
    await client.create_custom_emoji(server=message.server, name="mojihere", image=image)
  File "C:\Users\bot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 2515, in create_custom_emoji
    img = utils._bytes_to_base64_data(image)
  File "C:\Users\bot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 247, in _bytes_to_base64_data
    mime = _get_mime_type_for_image(data)
  File "C:\Users\bot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 238, in _get_mime_type_for_image
    if data.startswith(b'\x89\x50\x4E\x47\x0D\x0A\x1A\x0A'):
AttributeError: '_io.BufferedWriter' object has no attribute 'startswith'`

Code:

```
if message.content.lower().startswith('!take'):
    mojiid = re.findall(r'<a:\w*:\d*>', message.content)
    mojiid = [e.split(':')[2].replace('>', '') for e in mojiid]
    with requests.get("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/{}.gif?v=1".format(mojiid[0])) as r:
        img_data = r.content
    with open('moji.gif', 'wb') as handler:
        handler.write(img_data)
    with open("moji.gif", 'rb') as image:
        await client.create_custom_emoji(server=message.server, name="mojihere", image=image)
```

Comment: You seem to be using a really old style of code? Do you know if you are using the rewrite or async branch and also which version?

Comment: @coolio85 I'm using async branch.